# What is the relevant application of mathematics?

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

I want to model an asset (like a currency) that is sensitive to relative economic performance between two countries, which can be measured by GDP (for example). This is a very simple case with many assumptions. My question only pertains to the maths behind this:

```
Can drift be modelled in Geometric Brownian Motion
```

If you were to randomly simulate the price path of such an asset (e.g. USDCHY – driven by relative economic performance in China and the US, which can be measured by GDP), would it be appropriate to model it using Geometric Brownian Motion where the drift, for each timestep, is defined by the simple difference between GDP growth rates? (disregarding vol or anything else).

Just wondering, in principal, if this violates any convention or model assumption.

Do you think this would be appropriate to use in real life?

Comment: Hi: that would make the evolution of the currency rate perfectly correlated with the GDP difference ( aside from the stochastic component of the GBM )  but that's not going to make the simulated currency behavior look like the movement of the actual currency. I'm not sure if that's your question ? Apologies if its not.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I see what you're saying. How would you approach this?

Comment: Hi : I'm still not so clear on your question. Are trying to mimic the stylized properties of the currency rate or trying to actually predict the currency ? Either way, its' not easy but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. The latter is harder than the former obviously.

Comment: and your user name is quite neat by the way.

Comment: In the standard GBM model of exchange rates (Garman–Kohlhagen) the drift is equal to the difference in interest rates between the 2 countries. So it *does* take into account "relative economic performance" to an extent.  But Mr. Leeds is right to ask what are you trying to do?